# How to embed "Exposed form in block" into top bar? Using foundation theme

Tags: views, nodes, theming, navigation

I have a product search view. I use the "exposed form in block" in order to have only the filters show on all pages and the results show on a separate page. I want to put my filters in the top bar. How would I embed the "exposed form in block"? I know how to embed a view but I cant figure how to embed the "exposed form in block." in the top bar (the nav). The biggest reason is because its not a region. So I cannot place the block in it from the structure>blocks. Ive tried moving my header region to be on top of the nav but this create issues also. I was thinking that maybe there is a way to print the "exposed form in block" in the page.tpl.php... is this possible? Or will I have to use a hook in the template.php? Or Can I redefine the nav bar as a region possibly?

Comment: @Bala please consider adding [help center reference links](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to custom off-topic reasons like this. cojomojo, the full text of what is forbidden is: *"Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided"*. If you can rephrase your question so it would not need a link in it to be readable, it may still be OK.

Comment: I went ahead and rephrased the question and updated it in order to comply with the terms and make my question clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Views UI -> create a page view
2. Set 'Exposed form in block' -> Yes
3. Go to Structure -> Blocks
4. Find the exposed filter block which you recently created and configure the Region and Visibility settings

EDIT:
to specify a new region modify .info file and page.tpl.php file of you page: e.g.
MY_THEME.info:

```
....
regions[top_bar] = TOP BAR
...
```

page.tpl.php:

```
...
    <?php if($page['top_bar']): ?>
    <div class="header_top_bar">
      <?php print render($page['top_bar']); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  ...
```

[Documentation](https://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7)

or if you want to insert a block into template file here is an [issue](https://drupal.org/node/1032068).

Comment: i didnt give enough detail the first time (I updated the question now), I cannot place the block in the top bar because its not a region.

Comment: @cojomojo I updated my answer

Comment: aha this was what I was looking for. Thanks so much